# Label MCE button in php file, so i can translate it

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using a custom MCE button in my wordpress custom plugin below is my code

```
function enqueue_plugin_scripts($plugin_array)
{
//enqueue TinyMCE plugin script with its ID.
$plugin_array["related_post_button"] =  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "index.js";
return $plugin_array;
}

add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "enqueue_plugin_scripts");
```

and the js index.js is

```
(function() {
tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.related_post_button", {

    //url argument holds the absolute url of our plugin directory
    init : function(ed, url) {

        //add new button     
        ed.addButton("related_btn", {
            title : "Add Related post shortcode",
            cmd : "related_command",
            icon: "custom-mce-icon",
        });

        //button functionality.
        ed.addCommand("related_command", function() {
            var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
            var return_text = selected_text + "[related]";
            ed.execCommand("mceInsertContent", 0, return_text);
        });

    },

    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },

    getInfo : function() {
        return {
            longname : "Extra Buttons",
            author : "Narayan Prusty",
            version : "1"
        };
    }
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add("related_post_button", tinymce.plugins.related_post_button);
})();
```

to translate anything i am using this code in php

```
_e( "text to tranlate", 'wp-related-articles-acf' );
```

but how can i achieve that when i have code in `index.js`  `title : "Add Related post shortcode",`

Please note everything is getting translated correctly, just wanted to know how can i achive that

I already tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_languages but didnt worked

Comment: IF need translated text in js script please use localize script wordpress. and get variable value in jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has its own language files that it uses to internationalize the UI:

https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/

If your plugin has custom text that needs to be translated you need to add those strings to the appropriate language files.  To use your example:

```
ed.addButton("related_btn", {
    title : "Add Related post shortcode",
    cmd : "related_command",
    icon: "custom-mce-icon",
});
```

The text `Add Related post shortcode` is the "key" in the key/value pair in the language file.  In each language file you then define the correct string.  For example the Spanish language file might look like this:

```
tinymce.addI18n('es',{
    "Add Related post shortcode":"Añadir código breve de publicación relacionado",
    "Ok": "Ok",
    "Cancel": "Cancelar",
    .
    .
    .
});
```

**Note:**  *Wordpress does this a slightly different way via some TinyMCE API's.  Please look at the file named `wp-langs-en.js` in the `<wordpress_root>/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs` directory for an example of how they setup the English language.  You could do the same for other languages as needed.*